# Do I need to pay tax in Italy if I'm inheritating in France?

Tags: taxes, inheritance, france, italy

I am inheriting 100k€ in my home country, France. The account is a french one. However, I am currently residing in Italy (I got an italian ID card, work, pay my taxes and live there 99% of the year). Do I need to pay taxes on this money?

Comment: You might want to see if there are any similar questions on [expatriates.se]